# How to post on Google+ from Android app without using share dialog

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to post on google plus from android app without using share Dialogue any idea??
here i have used Google play service librarys for integration and getting a share dialog to post on google plus.

Comment: by using social auth adapter you can do it

Answer (score 2):

Google does not allow write google post automatically to avoid spam. You must use Share Dialog.

PS: Do not use capital letters

Comment: thanks,Is there any way to process the share dialog in background.without clicking share again and again i.e.once in android app and again in share dialog